# Gold vs. bronze badge color difference too subtle

Tags: feature-request, badges, design

The color difference between gold and bronze badges are too subtle to be noticed. Can they be made more saliently different?

Especially, with black background, they are almost indistinguishable to me. On the page that shows the inventory of badges, where the badges are aligned vertically, I almost cannot tell which ones are gold and which ones are bronze.

I agree with some of the proposals below, but even just making the gold more yellow and bright, and the bronze more brown/orange and dark can help. Or if just either of them were outlined with a different color, that could help too.

Comment: I find them easy to distinguish, one is brown and the other one is yellow. Maybe you need to adjust your monitor settings?

Comment: They're usually easy to distinguish when next to each other, but when you're only seeing one of the colors, it's harder. This is more of a problem on some sites than others.

Comment: @Bobby I access SO from a few different computers. I don't think the monitor setting is particularly bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the gold badges could be blinking?

[image]

:)

Comment: I heard that [pulsing is the new blink](http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/pulse.html) (visit with webkit-based browser).

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: Why not just put "GOLDIE GOLDIE GOLD!" in a friggen marquee tag.

Comment: @All, err, don't know if my smiley betrayed it or not, but I was only joking...

Answer (score 5):

Should be like that?

[image]

I don't think so!

Comment: Haha, no. Clearly the difference between gold and bronze is still too subtle.

Comment: The design is good but is too big! The color is too subtle.

Comment: Actually, ribbons with different colors may help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Gold badges shouldn't be made with traditional internet cement, they should be rendered as jquery web cement

Comment: +1 You are Steve Jobs!